# Big O notation of an algorithm

Tags: big-o, discrete-mathematics

```
i := 1
t := 0
while i <= n:
    t := t + i
    i := 2i
```

So I counted the number of operations in this pseudocode as 3n+2 and after this determined that the algorithm must be O(n). I am confused about the while loop since it is less than or equal to n instead of just less than n, does this increase the number of operations?

Comment: What you are missing is the effect of `t := 2i` .... on the *next* iteration of the loop.  Count again.  Alternatively, calculate the values that `i` takes over multiple iterations.

Answer (score 2):

> I counted the number of operations in this pseudocode as 3n+2

How? It should be a lot closer to O(log(n)), because at each step (except for the first step, which is passed) you're basically doing:

i := 3i

Thus, i is growing exponentially instead of linearly. Do a couple of example with n being really large (>1000) and see how quickly i can catch up.

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thanks